# Two boolean expressions equivalence. Co-NP?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, np

**PROBLEM** : *Having two boolean formulas we need to say if they have the same truth table*

Ex: `(x1 v x2)∧(¬x1 v x3)`   and `(¬x1 ∧ x2) v (x1 ∧ x3)` have the same values for all the combinations of (x1, x2, x3)

I have a few ideas: this problem may be at least as hard as the Tautology problem.

It might be easier to prove the correctness of an "NO" answer, than an "YES" one (Co-NP), but I don't know how to proove it.
Also, what is the certificate in here? Is it the answer "YES" or "NO" ?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `A==B` is `(A and B) or ((not A) and (not B))`. So it's possible to reduce it to the tautology problem. Conversely, given A, `A == T` is a reduction of a tautology problem to an expression equivalence problem. So it's co-NP (and in fact, co-NP complete).

Comment: Thank you. Why wouldn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Denis_Rozimovschii I fleshed it out into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Definitions

Let's say `A == B` means `A` and `B` always evaluate to the same boolean expression given any assignment of the free (boolean) variables `x_i`.

The boolean expression equivalence problem is, given `A` and `B` to say whether `A == B`.

The boolean tautology problem is, given `A`, whether for all possible assignments of the free (boolean) variables `x_i`, `A` evaluates to true.

### Equivalence of the two problems.

`A==B` is the same as `(A and B) or ((not A) and (not B))`. So it's possible to reduce an instance of the boolean equivalence problem to an instance of the tautology problem. Conversely, given `A`, `A == T` is a reduction of a tautology problem to a boolean expression equivalence problem.

So boolean expression equivalence is co-NP, and in fact it's co-NP complete since it's equivalent to the co-NP problem of boolean tautology.

### Certificate of non-equivalence.

You ask for a certificate for the co-equivalence problem. That's a proof that `A != B`. That's simply an assignment of the free variables `(x_i)` such that the two boolean formulae evaluate to different results. You can check this in polynomial time by evaluating both expressions.